# How do I make a child component just run if click a link on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have two component

My first component(parent component) like this :

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="item in invoices" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                ...
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    ...
                    <a href="javascript:"
                       class="toggle-show"
                       aria-expanded="false"
                       data-toggle="collapse"
                       :data-target="'#' + item.id"
                       @click="show(item.id)">
                        Show <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" :id="item.id">
                <order-collapse/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
    import orderCollapse from './orderCollapse.vue'
    export default {
        ...
        components: {orderCollapse},
        data() {
            return {
                invoices: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        ...
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        ...
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            show(id) {
                // orderCollapse executed if this method run
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

My second component (child component) like this :

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-collapse">
        <!-- this is used to display detail by id -->
    </table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'order-collapse',
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If the parent component executed, the child component automatically executed too

I want if the parent component executed, the child component not executed

I want the child component executed if user click show link

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a property (`displayedIds`) to hold the display status of each `order-collapse` and then condition their display using `v-if`:

```
<div ... v-if="displayedIds[item.id]">
    <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
</div>
```

And, considering `displayedIds` is initially declared as `{}`, you would have the `show()` method as:

```
  methods: {
    show(id) {
        // orderCollapse executed if this method run
        this.$set(this.displayedIds, id, true); // use $set to be reactive
    }
  },
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('order-collapse', {
  template: "#oc",
  name: 'order-collapse',
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('order-collapsed mounted for id', this.id);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      displayedIds: {},
      invoices: [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show(id) {
      // orderCollapse executed if this method run
      this.$set(this.displayedIds, id, true);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="item in invoices" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                ...
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    ...
                    <a href="javascript:"
                       class="toggle-show"
                       aria-expanded="false"
                       data-toggle="collapse"
                       :data-target="'#' + item.id"
                       @click="show(item.id)">
                        Show <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" :id="item.id" v-if="displayedIds[item.id]">
                <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<template id="oc">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-collapse">
        <!-- this is used to display detail by id -->
        <tr>
          <td>ID: {{ id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

Another possibility is having `displayedIds` as an **array** instead of an object. This way you could not use `$set`, just a regular `.push()`:

```
methods: {
  show(id) {
    // orderCollapse executed if this method run
    this.displayedIds.push(id);
  }
},
```

And condition the display using `.includes()`:

```
<div ... v-if="displayedIds.includes(item.id)">
    <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
</div>
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('order-collapse', {
  template: "#oc",
  name: 'order-collapse',
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('order-collapsed mounted for id', this.id);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      displayedIds: [],
      invoices: [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show(id) {
      // orderCollapse executed if this method run
      this.displayedIds.push(id);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="item in invoices" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                ...
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    ...
                    <a href="javascript:"
                       class="toggle-show"
                       aria-expanded="false"
                       data-toggle="collapse"
                       :data-target="'#' + item.id"
                       @click="show(item.id)">
                        Show <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" :id="item.id" v-if="displayedIds.includes(item.id)">
                <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<template id="oc">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-collapse">
        <!-- this is used to display detail by id -->
        <tr>
          <td>ID: {{ id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

Finally, if you find easier to reason, the `display` flag could be **in each `item` itself, as a property**.

In this case, the `show` should receive the whole `item` (not just `item.id`):

```
<a ... @click="show(item)">
```

The display would use just `item.displayed`:

```
<div ... v-if="item.displayed">
    <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
</div>
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
  show(item) {
    // orderCollapse executed if this method run
    this.$set(item, 'displayed', true);
  }
},
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('order-collapse', {
  template: "#oc",
  name: 'order-collapse',
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('order-collapsed mounted for id', this.id);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show(item) {
      // orderCollapse executed if this method run
      this.$set(item, 'displayed', true);
      // you could use `item.displayed = true` if you declared `displayed: false` in each item at data
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="item in invoices" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                ...
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    ...
                    <a href="javascript:"
                       class="toggle-show"
                       aria-expanded="false"
                       data-toggle="collapse"
                       :data-target="'#' + item.id"
                       @click="show(item)">
                        Show <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" :id="item.id" v-if="item.displayed">
                <order-collapse :id="item.id"></order-collapse>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<template id="oc">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-collapse">
        <!-- this is used to display detail by id -->
        <tr>
          <td>ID: {{ id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

*Which approach is the recommended?* It boils down to taste. If you can/don't mind appending the `displayed` prop to each item, I think it is the simplest solution. Otherwise I'd go with the first (`displayedIds` as an object), unless it gives you the yikes, in which case I'd pick the array solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems I need you help again :) Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685100/how-to-call-ajax-only-when-show-detail-on-vue-component